# Display video stream from LAN port inside HTML page

Tags: html, iframe, camera, server, video-streaming

I am confronted with a very simple problem but I couldn't find any solution or piece of information through the internet.

I have a camera sending a video stream to an Ubuntu server (with fixed IP 192.168.1.100), through the port 8081, and I would like to "capture" this stream to display it inside a nice HTML page.

From inside my local network, I simply use the HTML iframe tag as follow and it works fine:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.100:8081"></iframe>
```

However, here is the problem:
from outside my local network, my webpage is correctly accessible through my domain name but the iframe stays empty. I believe the reason is (correct me if I am wrong) that since the HTML code is executed in the browser, the address "http://192.168.1.100:8081" of the iframe tag doesn't point to my server anymore.
Therefore, the first thing I tired is to replace the previous iframe tag with the following one:

```
<iframe src="http://MY_DOMAIN_NAME:8081"></iframe>
```

However, this cannot work because I didn't forward the port 8081 of my router (and I cannot do it because otherwise everybody will be able to see my video stream without any access control).

Do someone have any idea about how to proceed ? More precisely, how can I access my video stream (embedded in an HTML page) from both, inside and outside my local network ?

Comment: No one ? Please don't hesitate to ask any clarification if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure I understand you, you want outside access to a LAN stream on your internal network, but don't want to open an external port on your router so that you can broadcast it out to the world, such that you would be able to view it from the outside.

You need to either have the stream saved as clips on your Ubuntu server and require a login to access from your server, externally, via a .php file makes the html document to allow viewing of recent clips of the stream; or, give up on viewing it externally from your network.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for answer, this is exactly what I wanted to do. I finally ended up solving the problem by making a Node JS proxy that displays the stream (embedded in a html/EJS page) after the user successfully logged in.

Comment: Can you explain more how you did that please?